# Can't use VPN feature from Network manager in Lubuntu

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, vpn

In Lubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, I am unable to use "Add vpn" option available in network manager, in right bottom panel where network manager shortcut is located, there is an option to add vpn and I am unable to click on that (it's greyed out).

I am using the VPN browser extension in Firefox and I know I can install third party vpn such as NordVPN.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me

Comment: The Firefox VPN won't help you with NetworkManager. You'll have to install some VPN provider, and if they're using openvpn, you'll have to get an .ovpn file, and import that into NM. Then the rest should be easy.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I know i can use third party vpn but i want to know how to use that "Add vpn" option and i know the fact that firefox extention is limited to that app.

Comment: How can you "add VPN" if you don't have a VPN provider installed? Do you have anything like `network-manager-openvpn` installed?

Comment: so u want to say that if i want to use that option then first i need to install any third party app? i was thinking that likewise android i need to enter user id, password and provider address.

Comment: Yes, but you have to have the proper NetworkManager software installed, and you still need access to a VPN server somewhere... paid or otherwise.